# SharePoint MS Flow - Send Email to People or Group field with Allow multiple selections and Allow selection of People and Groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, ms-flow

Could you please help me to send email to People or Group field using MS Flow
with Allow multiple selections "Yes"
and Allow selection of "People and Groups".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create the "Person or Group" Column

[image]

2.Create MS Flow

- Add a Trigger "**When an item is created**"
  [image]
- Add an Action "**Get item**"
  [image]
- Add an Action "**Data operations - Select**"
  [image]
- Add an Action "**Initialize Variable**". I named it as '**OriginalArrayAttendees**'. Type as '**Array**' and Value will be **the Output from previous 'Select' action**, we get only the Attendees Mail address in the array variable.
  [image]
- Add an Action "**Initialize Variable**". I name it as '**AttendeesEmail**'. Type as '**String**' and Value as blank at this stage.
  [image]
- Add '**Apply to each**' where **the output of variable 'OriginalArrayAttendees'** is entered.
  [image]
- Add an Action "**Data operations - Compose**" and in expression enter "**concat(item()?['Attendees'],';')**"
  [image]
- Add an Action "**Data operations - Compose**"
  [image]
- Add an Action "**Set Variable**"
  [image]
- Add an Action "**Send an email**". In the "**TO**" field it will be the **'AttendeesEmail' variable**. Rest of the body you can enter the way you want.
  [image]

3.Save and Test it.

More information, please refer to:

- **[Microsoft Flow | Send mail to Multiple recipients from SharePoint
  Person Or Group field.](https://sharepointmadeeasy.blogspot.com/2018/02/microsoft-flow-send-mail-to-multiple.html)**

===================== **Updated Answer** =====================

**Please following steps:**

1.Add a Trigger "**When an item is created or modified**"

2.Add an Action "**Get item**"

3.Add an Action "**Data Operation -- Select**"

- In 'Select' Action '**From**' (input for select) will be the '**Attendees**' Field.
- Map Key '**Attendees**' to Value '**Attendees Email**' (as only email can be used to send a mail.)

[image]

4.Add "**Initialize Variable**". I named it as '**OriginalAttendees**'. **Type** as '**Array**' and Value will be the Output from previous 'Select' action.

[image]

5.Add a Control "**Condition**". The condition is "**Attendees Email**" equal "**null**"

[image]

6.**If yes**.

- Add an Action "**List group member**" and select your group name.
- Then, add an Action "**Send an email (V2)**"

[image]

7.**If not.**

- Add '**Apply to each**' where the output of variable '**OriginalAttendees**' is entered.
- Then, add '**Apply to each**' where the output of variable '**(Get item) Attendees**' is entered.
- Next, add "**Append to array variable**".

**Name:OriginalAttendees    Value: Attendees Email**

- Lastly, Add an Action "**Send an email (V2)** "

[image]

[image]

Comment: If we add both Users and SharePoint groups it's got failing...

Comment: Hi, Pradeep Kolli. I have updated my answer. Hope this can help you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks you for your help and response. The only change was get SP group email block. If it's custom field we can't get the SP Group ID. So, mostly we need to use REST Call to get it rather then List Group Members

Comment: Hi EchoDu, Thank you help...