# Having a problem with Apply To Each in a simple email flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, power-automate, person-or-group

I'm creating a simple alert email flow. When an existing item is modified -> Send an email (V2).

The problem is I need to CC all the users in a Person/Group field with Multiple Users checked. When I add this Dynamic Content to the CC field, it immediately puts my email in an "Apply to each" box.

I'm not sure what to put in the "select an output from previous steps" field. I just know my emails wont send with it added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a string variable to capture all emails and then finally use that in string variable in email action like below:

[image]

Ensure that within "Append to string variable" you add **semicolon** towards the end as a separator.

**References**:

1. [Send one e-mail to multiple selection person or group column](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-one-e-mail-to-multiple-selection-person-or-group-column/td-p/841370)
2. [Multiple selection people picker causes multi emails](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Multiple-selection-people-picker-causes-multi-emails/td-p/564839)

Comment: This put me in the right direction. I needed a little more step for step help, which i found here : https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-I-need-to-send-email-to-multiple-user/td-p/476200

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Create the "**Person or Group**" Column named "Reviewer"

[image]

2.Create the below Microsoft Flow

[image]

3.Save and Test this flow

[image]

**Here is a similar case for your reference:**

- [SharePoint MS Flow - Send Email to People or Group field with Allow
  multiple selections and Allow selection of People and Groups](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289501/sharepoint-ms-flow-send-email-to-people-or-group-field-with-allow-multiple-sel)

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks for me at the "Select" portion. It again forces an "Apply to Each" as soon as i drop Reviewer field in their.