# Multiple Approvers email

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I have a SharePoint list that on a certain trigger needs to start an approval process for multiple users - depending on the situation this can be between 3 and 6 approvers. I started with a column that accepted multiple users (Person or Group - name with presence)then in my flow added the select and join function so that the output lists all the approvers email addresses into the body of an email (they are joined by ";").
This works fine in the email I am sending to the initiator (in the body) but when I want to use the same output to send an email to all approvers it fails (in the To:field). It works if there is one approver but if more it fails:
The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Send_an_email_(V2)' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'emailMessage/To' is required to be of type 'String/email'. The runtime value '"value@name.co.uk";"value@name.com;"' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'string/email'.
*(email address anonymised)*

Does anyone know how I can get the flow to send an email to all approvers listed in the column?

Comment: What you did surely works. So I would look at the outputs of the Join actions Are you sure that the output is like this: xxx@xxxx.co.uk xxxx.xxxx.co.uk? It looks like there is quote marks around each email, and that probably wont work.

Comment: Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299759/having-a-problem-with-apply-to-each-in-a-simple-email-flow/299761#299761) & let me know if it helps.